# How to make tags permanently show on tumblr?

Tags: css, tags, hover, tumblr

I am currently using [this](http://pastebin.com/kxKJ8S22) theme on my tumblr, and was wondering how to make it so the post tags are permanently showing, rather than just when the user hovers over the post?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind linking to where the theme is in use?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry! It's http://flamiekitten.tumblr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or comment out line 617: `opacity: 0;` This is what is making the tag div invisible until the post div is hovered over. By removing it, the div will default back to `opacity: 1;`

You can probably remove the transition lines from the `#tag` block and I'd imagine you'd be fine removing the `.entry:hover #tags` block too. They're not going to hurt anything if you leave them in though.